# Access DOM objects in SWT Browser

Tags: java, dom, browser, swt

Is it possible to access DOM objects by SWT Browser?

One solution is to execute javascript and add some BrowserFunction
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java

but I'm looking for some mapping to DOM objects, and operate on this objects. I need this for listening input changes and I'm using SWT 4.3

Answer (score 0):

See [example 17.86.15.Browser: query DOM node value](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/BrowserqueryDOMnodevalue.htm)

and [17.86.14.Browser: modify DOM (executing javascript)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/BrowsermodifyDOMexecutingjavascript.htm)

There is a trick used:        /*
         * Use JavaScript to query the desired node content through the Document
         * Object Model
         * 
         * Assign result to the window property status to pass the result to the
         * StatusTextListener This trick is required since `execute`
         * does not return the `String` directly.
         */